# Performance Issue in spark on EMR

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am running spark job on EMR in a 36 node cluster by executing an iceberg insert selecting values joining multiple tables. One of the stage is not evenly distributing the load across nodes or few nodes are running long time where as others complete in quick time. Please find below the picture from spark ui. What is the best approach I could take to resolve this?
I have set spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled and maximizeResourceAllocation to true

[image]

I have been looking at spark ui to understand more on how it is progressing